# Decryption of AES created with sjcl.js in ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby, encryption, aes, sjcl

Hi so lets assume that client-side has a key that is not transfered via the same channel as the encrypted data.

What I am trying to accomplish is to decrypt the result of [Stanford Javascript Crypto Library (sjcl)](http://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/) in ruby. or for a generalisation in any other language that has a crypto library that has support for AES.

Here is what I am doing in javascript:

```
sjcl.encrypt('stack-password', 'overflow-secret')
```

And this is what I get in return:

```
{
  "iv": "Tbn0mZxQcroWnq4g/Pm+Gg",
  "v": 1,
  "iter": 1000,
  "ks": 128,
  "ts": 64,
  "mode": "ccm",
  "adata": "",
  "cipher": "aes",
  "salt": "pMQh7m9Scds",
  "ct": "H6JRpgSdEzKUw2qEO1+HwIzAdxGTgh0"
}
```

So what I'm actually asking is, which of these parameters I need(assuming the server already has the "stack-password" key) in order to decrypt the secret server-side, and which library should I use?
May be having AES decryption library is not enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those coming here from Google, I managed to use the sjcl library to encrypt on Appcelerator's Titanium and decrypt on Ruby/Rails.

Encrypt (javascript):

```
var data = SJCL.encrypt('your key here', 
                        'plain text', 
                        { mode: 'gcm', 
                          iv: SJCL.random.randomWords(3, 0) });
```

The important bit is using a smaller IV.

Decrypt (ruby):

```
def self.decrypt(h)
  h = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(JSON.parse(h))

  key = OpenSSL::PKCS5.pbkdf2_hmac('your key here', Base64.decode64(h[:salt]), 1000, h[:ks]/8, 'SHA256')

  puts "Key: #{key.unpack('H*')}"

  puts "Salt: #{Base64.decode64(h[:salt]).unpack('H*')}"

  c = OpenSSL::Cipher.new("#{h[:cipher]}-#{h[:ks]}-#{h[:mode]}")

  c.decrypt

  c.key = key

  c.iv = Base64.decode64(h[:iv])

  puts "IV: #{Base64.decode64(h[:iv]).unpack('H*')}"

  c.auth_data = ""

  c.update(Base64.decode64(h[:ct]))
end
```

Comment: "The important bit is using a smaller IV."

Thanks — this was the the key for me. It seems like have to use a 96-bit IV for SJCL & OpenSSL to be compatible.

Answer (score 10):

The following **can not** be negotiated a head of time (or hard coded).

- `ct`: cipher-text your encrypted data, obviously
- `iv`: initialization vector, should be unique and not be reused with the same key for [AES-CCM](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3610)
- `salt`: random, and is used to create the key from password with [Pbkdf2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2898)
- `adata`: additional authenticated data, is plain text data that you want to include but ensure that it has not been tampered when using [AES-CCM](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3610). If you aren't ever going to include any data then you can ignore it (you would have had to pass it with the plaintext in sjcl).

The following you **can** negotiated a head of time (or hard coded), in fact you **shouldn't** plug these values in on the server encryption api, when transmitted **unauthenticated** and expect security. `adata` wouldn't be a bad place for `v`, `iter`, or `ks` if you wanted it to be changeable based on the client

- `iter`: iterations for [Pbkdf2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2898), this just needs to be high enough to slow down bruteforce on your password needs to change with the speed of hardware in the future.
- `ks`: keysize to know what size key to generate with [Pbkdf2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2898), needs to change with the amount of security in future
- `ts`: tagsize to know what size authentication tag is part of your cipher text
- `cipher`: If you will only support AES, then you can just assume.
- `mode`: if you will only support [AES-CCM](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3610) than you can just assume.
- `v`: If you will only support one version of sjcl in the future than you can just assume.

With ruby using the [OpenSSL library](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/Cipher.html) seems like it could work as long as your OpenSSL supports `AES-128-CCM` `puts OpenSSL::Cipher.ciphers` to check. And it does support [generating keys using pbkdf2](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/PKCS5.html), but you do need to use Sha256 digest to be compatible with sjcl, which is again dependent on your version of openssl.

Comment: Hi, any idea how to add support for AES-128-CCM?

Comment: Should just require a newer version of the c library.

Comment: Do you have any ideas about what version of OpenSSL supports this? I have "OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012" which is the latest version on openssl.org

Comment: Same here, I'm getting `unsupported cipher algorithm (AES-128-CCM)` even after upgrading to the latest version of OpenSSL.

Comment: Make sure your ruby version is linking against the newer OpenSSL, it was the answer for someone else's question about AES-GCM http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/30344/why-does-openssl-not-include-aes-256-gcm

Comment: @jbtule: I think API support is not currently complete even in the GitHub trunk.

Comment: @RichardCook didn't know openssl was on github now. Unless it's been removed, AES-128-CCM, is part of openssl.

Comment: @RichardCook Doesn't look like it's been removed https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/modes/ccm128.c

Comment: I've sent mail to the project maintainers seeking clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, I wrote up a translation of SJCL into pure Ruby (at least for the CCM parts). This doesn't require updating OpenSSL, but it's a bit slower.

You can find it at https://github.com/mdp/sjcl_rb

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks man, although i'm not sure how smart it is to re-implement AES in ruby, these algorithms get patched all the time...